# Built in Numpy Exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, numpy

In numpy are there any generic exceptions that can be called? 
From numpy docs I only saw specific ones such as [`LinAlgError`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.LinAlgError.html#numpy.linalg.LinAlgError)

For example, I know that Python has these error types built in:

- `Exception`
- `StandardError`
- `ArithmeticError`
- `ImportError`
- `IndexError`
- `KeyError`
- `NotImplementedError`

etc.

Answer (score 3):

No, `LinAlgError` doesn't inherit from anything. It's a generic error for when the linear algebra fails.

```
>>> numpy.linalg.LinAlgError.__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.Exception'>,)
```

If you explain the particular circumstances under which you would like to raise this 'generic exception', we might be able to suggest what to use.